# Trace all activity of an oracle session

Tags: sql, oracle, session, trace

I'm facing a small issue & I need your help if you have the time to do that, Please :)

I'm trying to setup a kind of audit to trace **ALL SQL STATEMENTS** executed by some specific sessions.

So I have created a trigger `AFTER LOGON` that enables a trace event (10046 (all levels tested) or using DBMS_MONITOR) for those sessions.

The script gives me the right result but in addition, it fills the trace with a lot of statistics & oracle internal queries, so I suppose that it will impact the database performance & will take too much disk space.

Is there any way to collect only user queries ? May be a specific trace can allow me do that ?

Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter recursive queries out of the trace file by formatting the file with `tkprof` using the flag `sys=no`:

```
tkprof input_file.trc  output_file.txt sys=no
```

The output file should be smaller and easier to read than the original trace file.  The file will probably still include some statements you don't care about, such as Spatial/SDO triggers.  But most of the behind-the-scenes statements will be excluded.

To only see the queries executed in the session, and exclude all statistics and internal queries, use the `record` flag to generate a separate file:

```
tkprof input_file.trc output_file.tk sys=no record=record.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ! The output is more better :) Is there anyway to delete statistics ou remove internal queries ?